# Filter date range "day before yesterday" in json query for logz.io api (elastic search)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logz.io

Context: Querying logz.io through the API.

The following query returns results for yesterday

`{
    "size":10000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
        { "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "now-1d/d", "lt": "now/d" } } }
                     ]
        }
    }
}`

I was hoping this one to return results for the day before yesterday

`{
    "size":10000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
        { "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "now-2d/d", "lt": "now-1/d" } } }
                     ]
        }
    }
}`

But it doesn't return anything. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing a `d` in the `lt` part

```
{
    "size":10000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
        { "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte": "now-2d/d", "lt": "now-1d/d" } } }
                                                                    ^
                                                                    |
                                                                  here
                     ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 seconds before my post. I'll delete mine :)